# FTP not working via PHP (ProFTPD) - Operation not permitted

Tags: php, ftp, proftpd

I try to upload a file via PHP to a FTP server running ProFTPD. This worked before like a charm. This is the code:

```
$this->con = ftp_ssl_connect($CFG['BACKUP_FTP_HOST'], $port);
ftp_login($this->con, $CFG['BACKUP_FTP_USER'], $CFG['BACKUP_FTP_PASSWORD']);
ftp_pasv($this->con, true); // Returns true
ftp_put($this->con, "/path/test.txt", __DIR__ . "/test.txt", FTP_ASCII); // Returns false, local file and remote directory exists (FTP_BINARY does not work also)
```

There are several funny PHP warning:

```
Warning: ftp_put(): Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted
```

If I try to change in the passive mode via `lftp`, it does not work also:

```
lftp ftp@test.de:/> quote PASV
501 PASV: Operation not permitted
```

The return of `FEAT` is the following:

```
211-Features:                
SSCN
SITE COPY
LANG en-US.UTF-8*;en-US
SIZE
PROT
CCC
SITE MKDIR
PBSZ
AUTH TLS
REST STREAM
UTF8
EPRT
SITE SYMLINK
EPSV
SITE UTIME
MDTM
SITE RMDIR
211 End
```

I think there is a problem with the FTP server, but other servers works with the configuration. Also, I can upload files with FileZilla. With PHP, the active mode is also not working.

The content of my proftpd.conf:

```
# Includes DSO modules
Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf

# If set on you can experience a longer connection delay in many cases.
<IfModule mod_ident.c>
IdentLookups                    off
</IfModule>

ServerIdent                     off
ServerName                      "FTP Server"
ServerType                      standalone
DeferWelcome                    off

MultilineRFC2228                on
DefaultServer                   on
ShowSymlinks                    on

TimeoutNoTransfer               600
TimeoutStalled                  600
TimeoutIdle                     1200

DisplayLogin                    welcome.msg
DisplayChdir                    .message true
ListOptions                     "-al"

DenyFilter                      \*.*/

# Use this to jail all users in their homes
DefaultRoot                     ~

# Allow continuation of uploads/downloads
AllowRetrieveRestart            On
AllowStoreRestart               On

# Users require a valid shell listed in /etc/shells to login.
# Use this directive to release that constrain.
RequireValidShell               Off

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                            21

# Workaround for nasty problem with FileZilla:
<IfModule mod_facts.c>
  FactsAdvertise off
</IfModule>

# Unlimited number of concurrent connections
MaxClients                      none
MaxInstances                    none

# Unlimited number of concurrent connections per IP/user allowed
MaxClientsPerHost               none
MaxClientsPerUser               none
PassivePorts 60000 65535
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
  TLSEngine On

  # Support TLSv1 (no more SSLv3 due to POODLE attack)
  TLSProtocol TLSv1

  # Safe ciphers:
  TLSCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
  # Are clients required to use FTP over TLS when talking to this server?
TLSRequired on
  # Server's certificate
  TLSRSACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/proftpd.crt
  TLSRSACertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/proftpd.key
  TLSCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/proftpd-ca.crt
  TLSDHParamFile /etc/proftpd/dhparams.pem

  # Authenticate clients that want to use FTP over TLS?
  TLSVerifyClient off

</IfModule>

# Virtual FTP users file
AuthUserFile /etc/proftpd/passwd

# Set the user and group that the server normally runs at.
User                            proftpd
Group                           nogroup

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new files and dirs
# (second parm) from being group and world writable.
Umask                           022  022
# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
AllowOverwrite                  on
TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
SystemLog   /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log
<IfModule mod_quotatab.c>
QuotaEngine off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ratio.c>
Ratios off
</IfModule>

# Delay engine reduces impact of the so-called Timing Attack described in
# http://security.lss.hr/index.php?page=details&ID=LSS-2004-10-02
# It is on by default.
<IfModule mod_delay.c>
DelayEngine on
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ctrls.c>
ControlsEngine        off
ControlsMaxClients    2
ControlsLog           /var/log/proftpd/controls.log
ControlsInterval      5
ControlsSocket        /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ctrls_admin.c>
AdminControlsEngine off
</IfModule>

# include additional configuration files
Include /etc/proftpd/conf.d/*.conf
# <EOF>-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Uhm, is this remote directory path correct `/.../test.txt`?

Comment: I have removed the full path.

Comment: But it is 100% correct and if you copy the path and paste it into FileZilla you get into the directory?

Comment: Yes. The directory is correct.

Comment: It looks like a permission problem with the directory. If running an unix server, try to chmod 775 'directory' -R , and chown the directory

Comment: No, it is not a permission problem. :-(

Answer (score 1):

You might configure a [`TLSLog`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_tls.html#TLSLog) file, and see what additional information is logged there.  I *suspect* (but the `TLSLog` might confirm...or not) that `mod_tls` is requiring that your data transfer connection reuse the same TLS session as used on the control connection, and that your FTPS client is not doing this.  This requirement can be relaxed by using the following in your `mod_tls` configuration:

```
TLSOptions NoSessionReuseRequired
```

For more information on this option, see the "NoSessionReuseRequired" description under [`TLSOptions`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_tls.html#TLSOptions).

Hope this helps!